# Vertically aligning text within an li

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small problem with this

```
    ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

    ul#menu li a {
        background: none;
        color: #999;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    ul#menu li a:hover{
        color: #7ac0da;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is, have an SVG inside the li and then have the text centered with the image rather than sat at the bottom of it.

```
<li><a href="~/"><img src="~/svg/iconmonstr-menu-6-icon.svg" height="30" width="30"/>Home</a></li>
```

Comment: got it no worries. '        ul#menu li a img
        {
           vertical-align:middle;
        }
'

Comment: I posted a community wiki answer.  Please except it so people know there's an answer here.  (Don't worry, I don't get any rep for your solution)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<ul>` to vertically align to the middle.

```css
ul#menu li a img { vertical-align:middle; }
```